# Is it possible to do INSERT + UPDATE + DELETE vs DELETE + INSERT?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am using SQL Server 2008 and this type of questions (INSERT + UPDATE vs DELETE + INSERT) was asked a number of time but my situation is kind of different based on my understanding. Please see the attached image below.

I have a table `BOM`, but later I need to update the quantity, insert a new material, and a material is not needed so I delete.

My questions are: for a very large table (10M+ rows)

1. is it possible to do INSERT + UPDATE + DELETE?
2. If yes, is it better than using DELETE + INSERT?

I searched and questions/answers were for case 1 but I need a solution for case 2.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the table/index structure, triggers, etc.

In certain cases you may execute UPDATE statement, but in fact in can be DELETE/INSERT operation in the background.

In certain cases it's faster to use 'soft deletion' - just mark the row as deleted, and then, during the quiet times (over weekend), you can schedule to delete the rows physically, defragment indexes, etc. You can use MERGE command to do INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE in one go, but you need to measure the performance comparing it with individual INSERT/DELETE/UPDATE statements. In many cases I prefer to do deletion first, then update, and finally insert.

It also depends on the number of changed rows... Sometimes it's faster to move the data to the new table (heap), then create the indexes there and finally drop/rename the tables.

Comment: I got better understanding now - thank you very much